# Can't understand why Dynamic Programming isn't working here

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to solve the [Word Ladder](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/) problem from ***leetcode***. In a nutshell, it asks you to write code that transforms one word into another by replacing one letter at a time, such that each intermediate string is also a word.

I know anyone can solve it easily with *BFS*. But I think *dynamic programming (dp)* technique will also work here. So I am trying to solve it with *dp*. For every sample test cases, it works fine. But this code fails for large input (System judges). .

Still now I am not understanding why *dp* won't work here?

Can anyone please give me a small input where this fails? You know it is almost impossible to test this code debugging by [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PVHn2snWgr/) large input.

Thank in advance.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> dp;
    int n;

    bool isOneDiff(string str1, string str2) {
        if(str1.length() != str2.length()) return false;
        int len = str1.length();
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(str1[i] != str2[i]) cnt++;
        }
        return cnt == 1;
    }

    int solve(string cur, int ind, const string endWord, vector<string> wordList) {
        if(cur == endWord) return 1;
        int &ret = dp[ind];
        if(ret != -1) return ret;
        ret = 100000000;    // Infinity
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(isOneDiff(cur, wordList[i])) {
                ret = min(ret, 1 + solve(wordList[i], i, endWord, wordList));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    int ladderLength(string beginWord, string endWord, vector<string>& wordList) {
        n = wordList.size();
        dp.clear();
        dp.resize(n+2, -1);
        int res = solve(beginWord, n, endWord, wordList);
        if(res >= 100000000) return 0;  // if res is greater than or equal to infinity then I have to return 0
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: DP solution is highly inefficient for this problem. why do you need to traverse across the whole recursion tree if you only need a shortest path from your source state to destination state

Comment: I'd attack this algorithmically first, and worry about the technique, dynamic or otherwise, only then.

Comment: Yeah, it is highly inefficient to use dp solution here. But `besides some of the recursion paths may not even reach the destination state so they never return`. I didn't get what you are trying to understand me. Isn't it the same path that we would create in BFS for this problem?

Comment: BFS *is* dynamic programming.   Your algorithm is broken, and will not always give the correct answer.  When you fix it it might be DP as well.

Comment: sorry for that comment, I removed it. It is not even possible to apply dynamic programming altogether in this problem because the recursion tree has cycles. There is no point in memoizing states because any cached state can get invalid on the next call

Comment: @MattTimmermans what makes you think that BFS is DP?

Comment: @mangusta optimal substructure: the shortest path to a node is calculated from the shortest path to its predecessor nodes.  overlapping subproblems: the same predecessor node is used in the calculation for all of its successors.   What makes you think that BFS is *not* DP?

Comment: @MattTimmermans you probably mean using BFS for finding shortest path in unweighted graphs. I meant BFS traversal in general : )

Comment: @mangusta  Why yes... this problem *is* finding the shortest path in an unweighted graph.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to memoize a DFS.  DFS will run into trouble on cycles, and also means that you have to explore a possibly large search space before you consider very short solutions.

Incidentally I would not suggest using BFS for this problem.  Instead I would suggest using A* search.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try with it.